# Print bars one above another in matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have tried following script ...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import pandas as pd

data = {"PEOI": [100,129,203,406,92,69,69,51,55,34,371], "PCHOI":[-3,-3,-4,10,37,2,-6,16,7,2,-44], "STKS":[4800,4810,4820,4840,4850,4860,4880,4900,4910,4920,4940], "CCHOI":[50,74,45,617,54,2,35,3,3,10,13], "CEOI":[177,182,67,562,118,135,112,30,32,15,184]}     
df = pd.DataFrame(data);

ax1 = df.plot.bar(x="STKS", y=["CEOI","PEOI"], rot=90, width = 0.9, title ="OPEN INTEREST BUILDUP", figsize=(10, 6), fontsize=20)
ax1.set_xlabel("STRIKES", fontweight ='bold', fontsize=25)

ax1.set_ylabel("CHANGE IN OI", fontweight ='bold', fontsize=25)
plot.show(block=True);
```

Now I have 2 queries...

1- How to make "CEOI"&"PEOI" bars to print one above another(overlapping completely) withe similar gridline as in below image
[image: bar pattern I need]

2- I need two plots at the same time(subplot) for the dataset from my DataFrame....
(a) PEOI, CEOI, STKS
(b) PCHOI, CCHOI, STKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want using pandas, so we will have to use matplotlib to build this plot from scratch. For the bars being in front of each other, it's just a matter of making two bar plots, giving them the same x values, and plotting them with different widths. For the subplots, I created a list for which data goes to which plot and looped through them, along with the axes, to create the plots. The rest of the code is for formatting (font size and rotation, labels, etc.).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {"PEOI": [100, 129, 203, 406, 92, 69, 69, 51, 55, 34, 371],
        "PCHOI": [-3, -3, -4, 10, 37, 2, -6, 16, 7, 2, -44],
        "STKS": [4800, 4810, 4820, 4840, 4850, 4860, 4880, 4900, 4910, 4920, 4940],
        "CCHOI": [50, 74, 45, 617, 54, 2, 35, 3, 3, 10, 13],
        "CEOI": [177, 182, 67, 562, 118, 135, 112, 30, 32, 15, 184]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

min_diff_x = np.diff(df.STKS).min()
w1 = 0.8*min_diff_x
w2 = 0.5*min_diff_x

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10,15))
for (y1, y2), ax in zip([("PEOI", "CEOI"), ("PCHOI", "CCHOI")], axes):
    ax.bar(df["STKS"], df[y1], width=w1, label=y1)
    ax.bar(df["STKS"], df[y2], width=w2, label=y2)
    ax.set_xlabel("STRIKES", fontweight="bold", fontsize=25)
    ax.set_ylabel("CHANGE IN OI", fontweight="bold", fontsize=25)
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
    ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid()
fig.suptitle("OPEN INTEREST BUILDUP", fontsize=20)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I need plots one below another not side by side plz.. and also add horizontal gridlines...

Comment: Look at [documentation for subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) and [documentation for grid](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid), pretty straightforward.

Comment: @PythonLearner I've made the changes, but be aware that Stack Overflow isn't a code request site. You don't just ask for code and expect people to write it for you. You have to try and do it yourself and only if you have tried and tried but cannot get it working do you ask for _help_ with fixing the code.

Comment: Ok dashed gridlines below the bar with specific lenghts for dash might be tricky, so here are the lines: `ax.grid(axis="y", linestyle=(0, (20, 8)))` and `ax.set_axisbelow(True)` (still easy to find in the docs though)